# Loki JSON logs labelling by field in the nested JSON

Tags: grafana-loki

Suppose I have logs in this format

```json
{
    "message": "SomeMessage", 
    "context": {
                   "appLabel": "varlabel"
                }
}
```

I want to do the `count_over_time` graph labeled by `{{.context.appLabel}}`

How can I do that?